# Как разбить интервал времени по неделям?

Tags: python

Есть dataframe ежедневный. Как разбить по неделям?
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1HuBZqhEMZJrk5pDEjfqc_y9q1tZ8k0OH

Answer (score 1):

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="Период", freq="W")).sum()
```